# Causing a rotating arc to touch another curve and not intersect it (Matlab code)

Tags: matlab, math, rotation, touch

I want to write a code where an arc stops rotating as soon as it comes in contact with a semi-circle.

I have written a code to do so, my arc **does not just touch the circle** but it **slightly intersects it**.

I have put rotation of arc inside a while loop by using `linspace()` to change theta. I used `polyxpoly()` for finding intersection. Condition for the `while` loop is that as long as I have empty array the loop continues, but as soon as I get a value from `polyxpoly()` my loop stops.

However, at the place of touch the theta value exceeds what I needed, so as a result I get an intersection.

How do I modify the code so that the arc will touch the semi-circle and not intersect it?

**Here is the output. Click the link below**

[Image of intersection but I need touch and not intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPI1l.png)

```
clc,clear
R = 5;                     % radius of a circle
r = 10;                    % radius of arc
aa = 60*pi/180;            % arc angle
ap = 0*pi/180;             % arc position angle
    
% defining the semi-circle about the origin
    
t = linspace(0,pi);
[x,y] = pol2cart(t,R);      % circle data
    
% Shifting circle centre to (3.5,0)
x=x+3.5;
y=y+0;
    
% defining the arc about the origin
t1 = linspace(0,aa)-aa/2+ap;
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(t1,r); % arc data
    
% shifting arc-lower-end to (14,0)
delx=14-x1(1); % Finding the x difference between arc-lower-end x-coordinate & 14
dely=0-y1(1); % Finding the y difference between arc-lower-end y-coordinate & 0
    
x1=x1+delx;
y1=y1+dely;
    
theta =linspace(0,pi,1000);
i=1;
xc=[];
yc=[];
    
while isempty(xc)&& isempty(yc)
    
    % create a matrix of these points, which will be useful in future calculations
    v = [x1;y1];
    
    % choose a point which will be the center of rotation
    x_center = 14;
    y_center = 0;
    
    % create a matrix which will be used later in calculations
    center = repmat([x_center; y_center], 1, length(x1));
    
    % define a 60 degree counter-clockwise rotation matrix
    R = [cos(theta(i)) -sin(theta(i)); sin(theta(i)) cos(theta(i))];
    
    % do the rotation...
    s = v - center;     % shift points in the plane so that the center of rotation is at the origin
    so = R*s;           % apply the rotation about the origin
    vo = so + center;   % shift again so the origin goes back to the desired center of rotation
    
    % this can be done in one line as:
    % vo = R*(v - center) + center
    % pick out the vectors of rotated x- and y-data
    x_rotated = vo(1,:);
    y_rotated = vo(2,:);

    [xc,yc] = polyxpoly(x_rotated,y_rotated,x,y)
    [xc1,yc1] = polyxpoly(x1,y1,x,y)
    
    i=i+1;
end
    
% make a plot
plot(x,y)
hold on 

plot(x1, y1, 'k-', x_rotated, y_rotated, 'r-', x_center, y_center, 'bo');
axis equal
```

I need to find way it contacts a circle and does not intersect it.
The code is in matlab.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection). Most, if not all, methods I know of in collision detection requires the computer to check for intersections of some sort. It's very difficult *(if not impossible)* to have two objects *"just touch"* in simulations, because you'll need the precise *(analytically solved)* location of the boundaries of those objects.

`polyxpoly()` is a function to *return the intersection* of two polygons. So unfortunately, if you insist that the arc *cannot touch*, then you cannot use `polyxpoly()`. In that extreme case, you'll have to solve some mathematical equation for when the tip of the arc coincides with a point on the circle perfectly, then simulate up until that point in time.

But realistically, what you need is a *finer* simulation *(although I personally think what you have alone is good enough)*. So in every simulation step, you calculate a smaller movement, so that *when the arc eventually intersects*, only a very small amount of the arc intersects.